# Camel Multicast not working

Tags: java, apache-camel, routes, multicast

Camel 2.11.0 here. I have the following Camel routes:

```
<route id="main-route"> 
    <from uri="timer://runOnce?repeatCount=1&amp;delay=10" /> 

    <to uri="bean:loggingBean?method=main" />

    <to uri="bean:processorBean?method=doSomething" />

    <to uri="bean:loggingBean?method=afterProcessing" />

    <multicast> 
        <to uri="direct:validator" />
        <to uri="direct:rejector" /> 
    </multicast> 
</route>

<route id="validator-route"> 
    <from uri="direct:validator" />
    <to uri="bean:loggingBean?method=validator" />
</route>

<route id="rejector-route"> 
    <from uri="direct:rejector" /> 
    <to uri="bean:loggingBean?method=rejector" />
</route>
```

...where the `loggingBean` looks like:

```
public class LoggingBean {
    public void main(Exchange e) {
        System.out.println("Starting main route...");
    }

    public void afterProcessing(Exchange e) {
        System.out.println("Processing input...");
    }

    public void validator(Exchange e) {
        System.out.println("In validator route...");
    }

    public void rejector(Exchange e) {
        System.out.println("In rejector route...");
    }
}
```

When I run this code, I get the following console output:

```
Starting main route...
Processing input...
In validator route...
```

Because we're *multi*-casting here, I would have expected it to also include the rejector's output and look like:

```
Starting main route...
Processing input...
In validator route...
In rejector route...
```

So it seems that the Multicaster is only sending to the first element nested inside it (in the Spring XML) and not the second. Hmmm, interesting. So then I changed the `<multicast>` element to look like the following:

```
<multicast> 
    <to uri="direct:rejector" /> 
    <to uri="direct:validator" />
</multicast>
```

This time, the console output is as follows:

```
Starting main route...
Processing input...
In rejector route...
```

So this is confirmed: the `<multicast>` is only broadcasting the exchange to the first child element listed underneath it. **Why, and how can I fix this?**

Comment: you want to send to both at the same time you should change to and async channel. I dont know what happen in multicast if the first channel gives an error

Comment: I'd try upgrading to the latest stable release of the 2.11 release branch (2.11.2) and then try again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[multicast](http://camel.apache.org/multicast.html) definitely sends to all endpoints...I'm not sure why its not based on your example

see these unit tests that do basically the same thing:

https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/camel/trunk/components/camel-spring/src/test/java/org/apache/camel/spring/processor/SpringMulticastTest.java

which uses this route:

https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/camel/trunk/components/camel-spring/src/test/resources/org/apache/camel/spring/processor/multicast.xml

Comment: Thanks @boday (+1) - in the interest of saving time, is there a way for me to define my own Java `Processor` impl and have it do the same thing that I'm trying to get the multicaster to do? I would need to take the `exchange.getIn()` and send it to `direct:validator` and then `direct:rejector`. Thoughts? Could you maybe post a code example? Thanks again!

Comment: Or, if not that, perhaps there is another way to send the exchange to both endpoints? They don't *have* to send at the same exact time; I could send the message to `direct:validator` and *then* `direct:rejector` if need be...

Comment: Does `direct:validator` change the message body? since, if not, I don't think you need to use multicast at all...

Answer (score 1):

I tested your routes and everything worked as expected:

```
<multicast>
    <to uri="direct:rejector" />
    <to uri="direct:validator" />
</multicast>
```

This logs

```
Starting main route...
Processing input...
In rejector route...
In validator route...
```

And with

```
<multicast>
    <to uri="direct:validator" />
    <to uri="direct:rejector" />
</multicast>
```

This logs

```
Starting main route...
Processing input...
In validator route...
In rejector route...
```

Perhaps, you read the wrong Camel configuration?